# What is the difference between using the Pattern Grid and using the Processing Pattern Encoder in Refined Storage?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

So I have been playing modded Minecraft 1.11.2 lately and I picked up the mod Refined Storage. I'm pretty new to the mod and was wondering if its more beneficial to use the Processing Pattern Encoder rather than using the Patter Grid, since using the Pattern Grid uses power and the encoder doesn't. So i'm curious to know, what is the difference between using the Pattern Grid and using the Processing Pattern Encoder in Refined Storage to make patterns?

Answer (score 1):

Processing Pattern Encoder is used for AutoCrafting in machines (Furnaces, Inscriber or third party blocks)

Patter Grid is used for AutoCrafting in the crafting table

[More info](https://refinedstorage.raoulvdberge.com/wiki/autocrafting)